# Speeding up the convergence for Steepest Descent Method

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

How would one speed up the convergence of the method of steepest descent when the minimum is in a very long, narrow structure? I know the fact that is a steep minimum covers more iterations to go down, but I'm unaware of how to project downwards in a more efficient manner.

Any thoughts can help!

Comment: From Bunday/Garside - Optimization Methods in Pascal - Edward Arnold 1987, pag. 85 "... If $P_0$, $P_1$ and $P_2$ are successive points obtained from using the method of steepest descent, it has been suggested that the method can be accelerated by making the next search in the direction $P_0 P_2$ ...". In some way this is related to the fact that (pag. 62) "... in the vicinity of its minimum any function can be approximated by a quadratic function ..." (Taylor's expansion).

Answer (score 1):

You could try *non-linear conjugate gradients* (nl-CG).

> The conjugate gradient method can follow narrow (ill-conditioned) valleys where the steepest descent method slows down and follows a criss-cross pattern. [[wikipedia]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_conjugate_gradient_method)

[This is a very good introduction to CG.](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake-papers/painless-conjugate-gradient.pdf) The nonlinear method is described in section 14.

Answer (score 1):

Two common classes of improved algorithm are

- (nonlinear) conjugate gradient, which works by choosing directions which are not independent each time so as to avoid criss- crossing as much.
- quasi-Newton methods such as BFGS which work similarly to Newton's method in that they use (approximations to) the second derivative.

Answer (score 0):

Scale the gradient by some factor at some iteration steps. The gradient points you in the right direction; if it's not fast enough, just give it a little shot of espresso. This method won't always work, but there are situations when it will.

Comment: In general, the gradient does not point in the right direction, e.g. if you look at http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake-papers/painless-conjugate-gradient.pdf, Fig. 17. Actually, in this particular case, I guess a factor smaller one would help, more like Ritalin than espresso.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest modification would be to scale the gradient by the inverse of the diagonal of the hessian:

$x_{k+1} = x_k −\gamma\mathrm{diag}(
(\frac{\mathrm df^2(x)}{\mathrm d^2x_1})^{-1},
(\frac{\mathrm df^2(x)}{\mathrm d^2x_2})^{-1},
\dots,
(\frac{\mathrm df^2(x)}{\mathrm d^2x_n})^{-1})
∇f(x_k)$